# Пропало верхнее меню в файловом менеджере Nautilus

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome

Как показать верхнее меню в Nautilus?
ОС: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

[image: top menu]

Comment: Как минимум при правом клике мышки, выпадет диалоговое меню, в котором есть пункт "Параметры" (если русскоязычная система, на английском вроде preferences или settings), в нем и вернуть назад в настройках. Те же действия касаются и терминала. Вроде тут ничего супер сложного. И так работает не только в Gnome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приложения Гном избавляются от меню в пользу кнопок с действиями. В последней версии меню выглядит так.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В версии что в 18.04 часть функций доступна из "гамбургера"( или "шестеренки" - не помню какой вариант попал в убунту), и пара пунктов при нажатии на заголовок окна на верхней панели.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если Вы не готовы к таким нововведениям, то лучше перейти на LinuxMint ( файловый менеджер Nemo )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Но ведь в ubuntu 18.04 должна быть не последняя версия наверное?

Comment: Что за тема на первом скрине?

Comment: @dmtr тема `arc`, есть в репах